# I want to replace text using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

In my code i am trying to replace `<Run Foreground="#FFFF0000"> with <Run Foreground="#FFFF0000" Text="`

right now i am using this

```
Regex.Replace(XMLString, @"<Run.*?>", "<Run Text=\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

which replaces `<Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">` with `<Run Text="`

I just want to replace > with text = " whenever i encounter `<Run` .

How can i archive this ?

Comment: How about posting your full xml and getting a better answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to capturing would be to use a lookbehind:

```
Regex.Replace(XMLString, @"(?<=<Run[^<]*)>", " Text=\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This will now only match `>` that are preceded by `<Run` after an arbitrary number of non-`<` character (so within the same tag).

Answer (score 2):

If this is an XML document, then you can just use XPath to select the `Run` elements and add attributes to the selected elements. It's a better option than using Regex.

Try something like this:

```
string txtAttributeName = "Text";
foreach(XmlNode element in xmlDocument.SelectNodes(".//Run")
{
    if (element.Attributes.GetNamedItem(txtAttributeName) == null)
    {
        XmlAttribute txtAttribute = xmlDocument.CreateAttribute(txtAttributeName);
        txtAttribute.Value = "Whatever you want to place here";

        element.Attributes.Append(txtAttribute);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this, but it should give you a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1)

```
Regex.Replace(XMLString, @"(<Run.*?)>", "$1 Text=\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

#### Option 2)

```
Regex.Replace(XMLString, @"(?<=<Run.*?)>", " Text=\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Note that, while equivalent, my version of option two is slightly more efficient (and generally recommended practice), because it avoids backtracking. (In fact, the same would apply to option 1)

Comment: A minor issue here: I haven't tested it, but I suspect that this won't work when this is a self-closing tag (i.e. `<Run Attribute="Value"/>`). It should be easy to fix that tho.

Comment: @Lirik, I suppose the OP is quite sure that the tag will contain something and will not be self-closing.

Comment: @m.buettner - Friend, find an error in your solution before I will downvote you...

Comment: @Ωmega the OP is just adding an attribute to an XML element.

Comment: @Lirik, how can you consider it as adding an attribure, when he is removing `>` from tag? There is a syntax issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the text you want to keep, then re-add it. I haven't test this, but:

```
Regex.Replace(XMLString, @"<Run(.*?)>", "<Run$1 Text=\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```